# how to alter a css class directly?

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible, to use javascript to edit the contents of a .css file directly? (In turn, impacting the style of the elements that use the class being modified?)

I've seen a few answers to such a question, but they all deal with the dynamic creation of HTML and css code in the html document itself, which I don't quite want...

Say for example, I have the following code:

```
*{
    color:red;
}
```

This makes ALL the text in the document go red. If I give the client an option to drop down and change the color of all the text to whatever he/she wishes, then the most logical choice is for me to go into the .css file, and edit the value of 'color' under the universal selector...

Ideas?

Comment: `If I give the client an option` (bad idea) ... `then the most logical choice is...`, no it's not.  It's much more logical to store it in a profile settings, either as a css file or in a database, or store the styling in cookies.  Regardless, your example has not justified why you need to change the original CSS.  CSS has precedence/order-of-operation loading as well as the `!important`, which would mean you should never need to modify the base styling.  If this was any large-scale site, you could muck something up.

Comment: Why is giving the client an option a bad idea? Because of the overhead on development? I just thought that it would be so much more simplier to change the base style... I mean, if you want to switch all text from red to blue, just going into the css, and changing the p{color:red} to p{color:blue} would've achieved the desired effect...

Comment: It's not the matter of giving them the option, it's about giving them the option that affects all users.

Comment: @vol7ron - Sorry mate, I'm not being thick intentionally, but I don't quite follow... if you had a website, say, stackoverflow here, and you've just finished watching 'The Matrix' (again), and were in the mood for some green on black terminal like theme, wouldn't you want to be able to select it from a dropdown on the top or bottom or something? I might be missing the point, and like I said, its not intentional, I'm just being slow today... :-(

Comment: I get what you're saying, but the way you put your example was, if someone want's the Matrix, you go into the base CSS file and edit it, such that if someone wanted the Matrix, everyone gets the Matrix, whether they want to or not. Whereas, I say put a matrix template in it's own CSS file and just import that (see my answer)

Comment: Ah! Now we're on the same page... But here's the thing, the server serves up the base css file, and when someone choses the matrix theme, some javascript changes the css values, and that's valid only for the specific client requesting the change, and only for that specific session... No? I think the cleanest, most used option is the profile preferences generation and storage, using cookies or the appcache... Thanks for your time mate... :-)

Comment: `I think the cleanest, most used option is the profile preferences generation and storage` ...exactly.  In the internet past, these profile/preferences were stored in cookies, but cookies have a limitation and users get upset when they delete all their cookies and find their preferences weren't saved.  So, it's common to store the preference on the server side and apply it during page creation (in asp/php/Perl code), avoiding the need for JavaScript.  This, however, does result in higher costs as the server is undergoing more work to process and construct those pages (vs the JS-cookie method)

Comment: Hmmm... Plus I'm a little weary of server side dynamic page creation for its costs on client side load times... I've come to appreciate client side scripting simply because of its 'Immediate' response, and creating entire sites on a single page is something of a 'challenge'... Lol, in no way am I speaking on behalf of the internet at large, but I believe there's some room for improvement.. So lets get to it, shall we? :-p

Comment: client-side performance depends on the computer that is doing the processing.  there are still many machines that are not running dual core, which increases loading times and really creates a delay.  I would say the majority, though, is safe.  this dynamic kind of page creation isn't all that taxing on the server, because it's a simple lookup - I was just posing that as something to consider.

Comment: @vol7ron - No doubt, there's an increased burden when client side processing is required, but as you said, that there's a majority of systems which should be in the green with regards to this... Plus, the technologies required to get the 'total' client side solution working are still somewhat stubs, and need more maturity... My assumption is that by the time they are mainstream, the client side taxation should be minimal, and I'd like to be prepared when that time comes... Not to mention, that slower internet connections (3G) will also greatly affect the load times when the server does it all.

Comment: Actually in terms of net performance, whether it's dialup, broadband, or something wireless like 3G; the server processing would probably be a little faster (albeit negligible), since the additional JavaScript would increase the number of packets being sent.

Comment: Hmmm, true... But if I were to cache the packets on first load? If it was a rather big site, I could technically 'package' it as an application, with an 'initial installation', wherein the site downloads and cache's most resources (CSS, JS, assets, etc.) and utilizes minimal bandwidth... Am I being overly hopeful about this?

Comment: You're over-optimizing, there are applications (such as CMS and forums) that are much more intensive on the serverside.  Cacheing the CSS would be the same regardless, the only thing you're saving is a database/file lookup and an if statement, which is basically nothing.

Comment: But in the situation where the site is an information kiosk (more or less) in that it doesn't accept any information (no user registration, no commenting, etc.) and only exists to display information. Caching the assets and resources in this situation will greatly improve the experience, no? (No doubt this is not a blanket solution for every possibility out there)

Comment: Cacheing is generally always a good thing, but you can do it in two ways.  You have to remember, though, that some people don't permit their machines to cache/keep-save information.  The other thing, with keeping things server side is that user's profile/preferences can be applied to multiple machines.  So whether the user is working on their desktop, workstation, laptop, tablet, etc and access your site, they'll have the same unified settings for their account; the JS/cookie method would have them set their preferences multiple times.

Comment: Hmmm... You make a good point about the multiple machines scenario... Honestly, I do that too, browse a site on the desktop, then switch over the iPad when I travel, and I expect the site to be the exact same way as I had personalized it... Fair enough Cap'n Vol7ron, this has been a most enlightening discussion... You sir, deserve a medal... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do all your css manipulation in a single style element you append to the head-
anything you put there takes precedence over the other stylesheets, and your users can 'backtrack' to the page defaults by deleting their changes, one at a time or all at once.

Using the last sheet (your new style element's rules) in the document.styleSheets collection, you can append new rules, delete old rules, or edit existing rules.

And you have a piece of text you can save on your server or in local storage for each user, possibly to add to the document the next time they visit.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of something along these lines... In addition to some of the other answers I've received so far, which allow me to the <style> tag itself, it would make sense for me to dump all of my editable css inside the html file itself... Sigh, work work...

Answer (score 2):

The way I would approach this is to save the preference in something like a profile and when the page loads, dynamically apply the preference using the page generator or using Javascript. Using the page generator would make things smoother as the CSS code will be in the page itself when it loads.

Comment: This is my fallback plan, I'd much rather not make it tedious like this, but I will if I don't have a choice...

Answer (score 0):

You can't add to the CSS with JavaScript, but you can add styles to an element or a series of elements.

If you want to give your clients control over the styles you can have them created with PHP. You'd basically just use your variables as values and have them link to the PHP file in the CSS link element.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/css.php" />
```

Comment: You see, the alternative I have, is that I create a class called '.red', and I have to apply it manually to EVERY element... I also create a class called '.blue', and when the user decides to change to blue, I need to replace the class of EACH element from .red to .blue... That's not feasible...

Comment: Alternatively, if I swap stylesheets based on what you said, I'll need a separate stylesheet for each property... If I allow changing colors, I'll need an entire stylesheet which declares all text as red, and another one for blue... So when change is requested, I just swap the red and blue stylesheets... But what happens when I expand scope of user control? They can change font, text-shadow, box-shadow, background colors, font-sizes, font colors, etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks interesting...

http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/change-style-sheets.shtml

Comment: Sorry mate, but what you've provided a link is a way to dynamically alter the stylesheet itself (the entire css file, and not just one property), and store the choice in a cookie... Which is nice, but I want to take it one step at a time...

Answer (score 0):

In short, it's possible to use javascript to change css. You can use jQuery and there are some examples here: http://api.jquery.com/css/.

Comment: This comes close, but its not exactly what I'm looking for... From what I understand, you're making alterations and/or additions to the inline style for a specific element, or a group of elements matching a specific query... What about global changes?

Comment: @Abhishek: You can change globally by using global selector. In spite of that, reading through the answers, I see that the approach of Rasika is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You could do...

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].getElementsByTagName('*');

for (var i = 0, length = elements.length; i < length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.color = '#f00';
}
```

Comment: It appears as though you are adding inline css... fair enough, your code achieves what I want, but I'd rather not rely on inline css... This implies, that if I want to give the user control over more elements, such as box-shadow, text-shadow, etc., I'll need to have multiple functions... Still, you method covers EVERY element... What if I want to only cover specific elements (say, all DIV's) but there're like, 90+ of them... ?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to alter the original .css file on the server, so that style change is maintained for the following requests. But JavaScript executes in the browser and .css files live on the server. So the short answer is, no, it cannot be done. Not practically anyway.

You could, if you really wanted to, create some JavaScript that makes an AJAX request to the server and then write some server side code to receive the request and modify the .css file accordingly. That would more trouble than it would be worth, and probably create an entertaining security vulnerability, so I would not recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for the insight... You make a good point about the security issue, so I ask you this then... What is the best way to tackle this? I want my users to be able to change global attributes, such as text-shadows, font-colors, box-shadows, background-gradients, etc. Essentially, I want them to be able to customize their experience through the few options I provide to them... Their changes need to be global, without me having to expand the code 3-4x its actual size...

Comment: The first approach that comes to my mind is the one you already discarded. Creating some (it does not have to be all) the CSS dynamically and adding it to the HTML document. If there are only a small number of options you could store them in a database (one option per column), and build the CSS from those options. There are still security risks storing in a database, but it is safer modifying a .css file directly because it is easier to validate the user's options and there is no messy file parsing involved.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I will backtrack if needed, I just find that holding several stylesheets can get messy, considering that I want users to be able to have a slider to adjust the thickness of the text-shadow, or a slider for the opacity of the container div's, etc. Temporarily, we can ignore storing client preferences, lets get the flexibility working, shall we? :-p

Answer (score 0):

#### Dynamically load CSS file, using pure JavaScript

---

```
var filename = "matrix.css";
var css      = document.createElement("link");

css.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
css.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
css.setAttribute("href", filename);
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(css);
```